# Power automate flow - Cannot use 'list rows in present table' in apply to each

Tags: sharepoint-online, excel, power-automate, flow, power-platform

My "Apply to Each" - "value" is coming from Get Tables, shouldnt it be coming from "List rows present in a table" but this option is not available in dropdown.

If  I do not have the get table and only use list rows and selec tthe table, I can get the "value" from list rows in present table.

How can I access the rows in the list table for my apply to each?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use your "Apply to each" action **inside** "Apply to each 2" action, after "List rows present in a table" action.

Then you will be able to use the value array from "List rows present in a table" action in your apply to each action.